# Initialising an int64 variable

Tags: ocaml

I tried initializing an int64 variable in the following way :

```
let k:int64 = 4000000000;;
```

However I got the following error message :

```
Error: Integer literal exceeds the range of representable integers of type int
```

How do I intialise k to a value of 4 billion? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`L` specifier](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual021.html#toc68) to indicate an `int64` literal:

`let k = 4000000000L;;`

Alternatively, since the number exceeds the range of int32, you can convert it from `float`:

`let k = Int64.of_float 4000000000.;;`

Comment: Cool thanks. Also is it correct for me to say that there is no value in making type declarations in the following way "let k:int64"?

Comment: Yes, it is. The type checker is able to infer the correct type.

Comment: It should be noted that the “alternative” proposal has issues for integers above 2^53 or so.